# Setting separate GtkTable column width

Tags: python, pygtk, glade

I'm building simple PyGTK app with Glade.

In one dialog I have table layout with labels in first column, and text entries in second column.

The problem is that two columns have always same width, and I want 2nd column to be wider then the first one.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a `gtk.Table` to display your widgets in your dialog. You can set the `homogeneous` property to `False`, so that cells in the table don't have the same dimensions.

After that, if the largest widget in the second column is wider than the largest widget in the first column (which I assume is your case), then the secound column will be wider than the first column as you need.

Comment: Great tip, thanks, that solved my problem. Now I have a new one, I want sth like this http://imgur.com/Yqxqq label - spin button - label, all 3 in horizontal box. First label is aligned left, last aligned left, but still, they are getting space between when resizing container. You can see similar behaviour if you open Tomboy preferences, Synchronization tab, and resize it. I want only last label to get space on its rightside, so all 3 widgets stick together when resizing. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: This is an issue related to `Expand` and `Fill`. From what you're saying, you probably want to set `Expand=False` for the second widget.

Comment: I just wanted to add X pad to 1st label, but only from the right side, but for some reason padding is added to both sides, even if justify is set to left. Strange?

Comment: For the benefit of other people that might have the same problem in the future, please don't use comments to ask new questions because those people won't be able to find them. Create new questions instead.

Comment: OK, posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456556/gtklabel-alignment-and-padding. Thanks.