# GtkLabel alignment and padding

Tags: python, pygtk, glade

I have GtkLabel in Glade with X align set to 0, X pad set to 5, Expand set to No.

Label is located under horizontal box together with spin button and another label.

The problem is that X pad is applied to both, left and right side.

I want it to be applied only to right side.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Xpad` is applied to both left and right.

**Glade 3.10**

If you just want to have a margin on the right, then change `Margin on the right` available in the `Common` tab:

[image]

**Glade 3.8**

Right click on the `GtkLabel` widget and select `Add Parent->Alignment`. Click in the `GtkAlignment` widget and set `RightPadding` to the desired value.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, there are no margin options for me. I'm using Glade 3.8.0. What is your version?

Comment: I'm using glade 3.10, but I've checked also in glade 3.8 and added an alternative solution that should work for you.